# Is there a way to run a function for a given amount of time in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on an application in Electron/Node that is supposed to collect some data. 
Data is streamed to a file using (pseudo-code)

```
function collectData(data) {
file.write(data+"\n");
}
```

Which is fired by an event

```
app.on('ready', (event, args) => {
  collectData();
})
```

How can I make sure the event calls the function for a given amount of time? Is there a cleaner and more efficient solution than defining a start and end time, and checking for `end > start` each loop?

Comment: What do you mean "calls for a given amount of time"? It only calls the function once, and that function appears to have a (near) constant runtime based on the context.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it better. I would like to call that function for e.g. 20 seconds only, and then stop.

Comment: You'll need to [edit] your question to provide a more concrete example, keeping in mind that it needs to be [mcve]. The body of `collectData()` heavily influences the recommended approach to answering your question.

Comment: Setting an end time and checking against it is probably a decent solution in a lot of cases, yep. Starting a timer with `setTimeout` might also be a good option. It depends on what you need to do when it stops and whether it’s important for that to happen as soon as the time is up, vs. as soon as an event happens outside the allotted time.